# Typescript function not called from Html while using RequireJs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, typescript, requirejs, node-modules

I am trying to use RequireJs to load Typescript functions in Html. I made a simple Alert function in type script as follows and it doesn't seem to get called.This should be simple, but i tried all the basic checks and not sure whats missing.

Eventhandler.ts:

```
export function Main() 
{
    alert("Hi");

 }
```

Eventhandler.js:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) 
{
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    function Main() {
        alert("Hi");
    }
    exports.Main = Main;
});
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "AMD",
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../appscriptJS"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

The main js file where the require configuration is present is app.js.

app.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/requirejs/require.d.ts" />
require.config(
{
    baseUrl: './appscriptJS',
    paths: { jQuery: '../scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' }
});

require(['EventHandler'], function(app){ app.Main();});
```

The respective js file, app.js:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    function Main() {
        alert("Hi");
    }
    exports.Main = Main;
});
```

Html page:
    ```
   Enter your mobile number:

````
<div><span id="message"></span></div>
<input type="button" class="btn-default" id="submit" value="Submit" />

<script data-main="app.js" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was so simple.
The data main attribute in require js api doesn't search in the base url given in the requirejs configuration file.

So, had to give the complete path for the app js file in the script in html as follows:

```
<script data-main="../appscriptJS/app.js" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>
```